# What is the remainder when dividend is divided by product of divisor with given remainder?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $ P(z) $ is divided by $ z+1 $ the remainder is $ -8 $ when $ P(z) $ is divided by $ z-3 $ the remainder is $ 4 $ find the remainder when $ P(z) $ is divided by $ (z-3)(z+1) $?

Comment: (1) What are your thoughts on this problem?  (2) You have $z-1$ in one place and $z+1$ in another.  Are those actually different, or should they be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the Euclidean Algorithm,the remainder of $P(z) $ on dividing by $(z-3)(z+1)$ is either $O$ or is of degree $1$.The degree cant be zero otherwise $(z-3)$ will divide $P(z)$ completely which is not true.So the remainder $r(z)$ is of degree $1$. so $r(z)=az+b. r(3)=4,r(-1)=-8$.On solving we get $a=-5,b=3$.Thus $r(z)=-5+3z$